# How to change a method from string result without a IF

Tags: c#, ranorex

I am doing test automation in C# inside Ranorex software.
I get the name of a button to click on from an XML file and the method :

`string deviceName = device.SelectSingleNode("./ButtonInTTS").InnerText.Replace(" ", "");`

I get a string whose name tells me which button to click in my application, then there is this method :
repo.TiTouchScreenApp.ToolbarListBox.**Button**.DoubleClick();

In fact in Ranorex you have the library of all the buttons and I need to change the name of Button to the result of deviceName.
For example if deviceName == "Automation", it will do 
repo.TiTouchScreenApp.ToolbarListBox.**Automation**.DoubleClick();

deviceName == "Temperature"

repo.TiTouchScreenApp.ToolbarListBox.**Temperature**.DoubleClick();

BUT I want to do this without a IF. Because I have a lots of button and I don't want :

```
if(deviceName == "Automation"){     
    repo.TiTouchScreenApp.ToolbarListBox.Automation.DoubleClick();
} else if(deviceName == "Temperature") {
    repo.TiTouchScreenApp.ToolbarListBox.Temperature.DoubleClick();
} etc etc...
```

Do you see a solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If repo.TiTouchScreenApp.ToolbarListBox returns a list of control e.g. Buttons then do something like this :

```
var button = repo.TiTouchScreenApp.ToolbarListBox.Buttons.Where(b => b.Name == deviceName).FirstOrDefault();

if(button != null)
{
  button.DoubleClick();
}
```

Comment: `'TiTouchScreen.TiTouchScreenRepositoryFolders.ToolbarListBoxFolder' does not contain a definition for 'Buttons' and no extension method 'Buttons' accepting a first argument of type 'TiTouchScreen.TiTouchScreenRepositoryFolders.ToolbarListBoxFolder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS1061) - `


:(

Comment: @xenom my answer shows the alternate of If you will need to find out what type does repo.TiTouchScreenApp.ToolbarListBox returns hence I said If repo.TiTouchScreenApp.ToolbarListBox returns a list of Buttons